# How to remove www for xampp

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I have been using this code in .htaccess to force www. for my website:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The problem is when I want to edit the website using xampp. When I type localhost it will redirect me to www.localhost which doesn't work. How I can remove the www. when using xampp?

Edit: I deleted these rules putting # before them and it seems to work in other browsers but in google chrome it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an exception for `localhost` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Also make sure to clear your browser cache to make it work since browsers do cache 301 URLs.